# redux initial state as first parameter is a bad practice

Tags: redux, default-value

In redux the initial state is provided by using a default parameter for the first argument `state`, while the second argument `action` does not have a default. However, I consider this a code smell  (and so do others such as [Airbnb guidelines](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript#functions--defaults-last)) since you always need to provide the first argument (and then would use `undefined` to get the default which is cumbersome). I totally understand why you would want to provide that initial state, but why do they not switch the arguments so the default is 2nd to bring code in compliance with common guidelines?

```
// bad
function someReducer(state = 0, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
  default: return state;
}

// good
function someReducer(action, state = 0) {
  switch (action.type) {
  default: return state;
}
```

redux forces our developers to use a bad practice which encourages them to do it in other places. Why would redux-developers still decide for such architecture?

***UPDATE***

The reason, why it is a *bad* practice to have defaults going first comes from language design itself. In JS the interpreter cannot tell what the intention of the developer was. As an example:

```
const giveMe = (goodHuman = true, candy) => (goodHuman && candy) ? 'candy' : 'tea';
```

So, will I get candy?

```
giveMe(true) // not clear! (but it is 'tea')
```

I cannot access the candy with a single parameter! But I guess the developer would have liked me to get some, right? However, `candy` is always `undefined` making the conditional expression evaluate to `undefined`. As a fallback the else-part is executed. It is not a clear intention and hard to guess what the developer wanted to express. Such code would not come through our review-process / QA.

So, in the following example, the developer made sure that we can access that candy if we want it and he beliefs that we by default are good humans who should get that candy.:

```
candy giveMe = (candy, goodHuman = true) => (goodHuman && candy) ? 'candy' : 'tea';
giveMe(true) // finally we get the candy!
```

Since people say that putting the default in front is a *best* practice with redux, I would consequently argue that redux has a bad design on the reducers' signature! It might origin from the fact that reducer-functions in general have a similar signature, but **they do not make the first argument optional** which would not make any sense! It argue that it is a bad design decision of redux to make it a "best practice" calling a function using `undefined`.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but if you switch the parameters the end result is the same. There is no performance bonus and your statement "since you always need to provide the first argument" applies to both function signatures

Comment: it is not about performance but about best practices.

Answer (score 1):

The signature of a "reducer" function as `(state, action)` is based on the signature of a callback you would pass to `Array.prototype.reduce()`, such as:

```
const sum = [1, 2, 3].reduce( (sumInProgress, currentNumber) => {
    return sumInProgress + currentNumber;
});
```

The first argument is the "accumulator" or "previous state" value, and the second argument is the "current item" value.  In Redux, those values correspond to the existing state, and the current action.  So, there is explicit precedent for that function signature.

As for initializing the state: you *could* always provide the app-wide initial state as the second argument to `createStore(rootReducer, preloadedState)`.  However, the encouraged approach is that each slice reducer should take care of providing its own initial state, and do so when it is called with a state value of `undefined`.  The built-in `combineReducers` function will ensure that each slice reducer is called on startup, thus neatly initializing each piece of the overall app state.

While you could explicitly check for `if(state === undefined) return initialState` inside of the function, it's shorter and simpler to declare the initial state as a default value for the `state` argument.

So, overall, this is *not* a bad practice, but rather a *best* practice for use of Redux.  Remember that style rulesets like the AirBNB guidelines are merely opinions, not strict rules that everyone must follow.

For more info on how Redux state initialization works, see the [Structuring Reducers - Initializing State](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/InitializingState.html) section of the Redux docs.

Comment: The array reduce function's signature is `arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue])` and the callbacks first argument (accumulator) is not optional.